# Import bacpac in SQL Server instance using VB.Net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, import, visual-studio-2015, bacpac

I have tried to search online code in VB.net for importing/restoring bacpac on my local SQL server instance but unable to find out. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using dacpac NuGet package. This will help you to solve the error.

Please refer following code.

> var services = new DacServices(ConnectionString);
>
> ```
>             using (BacPackage bacpac = BacPackage.Load(bacpacfileStream))
>             {
>                 services.ImportBacpac(bacpac, DatabaseName, new DacAzureDatabaseSpecification
>                 {
>                     MaximumSize = 500,
>                     Edition = DacAzureEdition.Standard,
>                     ServiceObjective = "S4"
>                 });
>             }
> ```